# what is javascript code for search query text appear in search box?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, search-box

i owned a web search engine and search query text is disapear after clicking on search, how to make search query text will appear after click on search ?

see http://www.squidgo.com

Comment: Edit you answer and add some lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
$searchvalue = $_POST['searchvalue'];
```

and in the Searchbox

```
value="$searchvalue"
```

should work